# c stack smashing detected

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I've created a file which prints Hello, world as many times at the user wants to give input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char message[10];
    int count, i;

    strcpy(message, "Hello, world!");

    printf("Repeat how many times? ");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    for(i=0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%3d - %s\n", i, message);
}
```

No matter what the number entered it always results in a "stack smash". Here is the program, can anyone come up with a conclusion to why it is doing this? Here is the "traceback" that occurs after the stack smash is detected:

```
sean@blue:~/programming$ ./a.out
Repeat how many times? 12
  0 - Hello, world!
  1 - Hello, world!
  2 - Hello, world!
  3 - Hello, world!
  4 - Hello, world!
  5 - Hello, world!
  6 - Hello, world!
  7 - Hello, world!
  8 - Hello, world!
  9 - Hello, world!
 10 - Hello, world!
 11 - Hello, world!
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x45)[0x1f8c75]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xe8c27)[0x1f8c27]
./a.out[0x8048524]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x129113]
./a.out[0x80483f1]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00288000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1577912    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00288000-0028a000 r--p 00178000 08:01 1577912    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
0028a000-0028b000 rw-p 0017a000 08:01 1577912    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
0028b000-0028e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0036b000-0036c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00454000-00470000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1573818    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00470000-00471000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 1573818    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00471000-00472000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 1573818    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00e7e000-00e9c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1573924    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00e9c000-00e9d000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 1573924    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00e9d000-00e9e000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 1573924    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 3801591    /home/sean/programming/a.out
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 00:14 3801591    /home/sean/programming/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 00:14 3801591    /home/sean/programming/a.out
08a9e000-08abf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b77e8000-b77e9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b77fc000-b7800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bff87000-bffa8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

Comment: You might find it helpful to turn up the warnings on whatever compiler you're using.  For example, when I used gcc with -Wall, it produced both "warning: control reaches end of non-void function" and "call to __builtin___strcpy_chk will always overflow destination buffer", the latter of which makes it clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 44):

Because `"Hello, world!"` is more than 10 characters...

Answer (score 18):

`message` can only hold 10 bytes. You are copying the string "Hello World!" which is 13 bytes (if you count the null character) and you will end up overwriting and corrupting the stack protector cookie.

The cookie is a random byte inserted by the compiler to make sure that you crash if the return address is modified on stack, preventing potential buffer overflow exploits.

If you are compiling with gcc, to experiment, try adding `-fno-stack-protector` switch to your compilation statement and trying again. The program will probably crash (but not with a error message like that) and will be vulnerable to buffer overflow exploits.

Comment: Note: the OP used "Hello, World!" - 14 bytes with the 0 terminator.

Comment: @mattnz Oh, I missed the comma. Screw it. It's okay. I'm not gonna edit the post again for that :)

Answer (score 4):

Your message array is 10 characters long (0-9), but if you count `"Hello, World!"` (without the quotes) it is 13 characters long. As such you are overwriting memory that isn't part of your array.

For reference, `strcpy()`, `strcat()` and most other C-string functions don't check the length of the array, they assume that you've given it enough space to work with.

So, you'll need to give your message array more space. But how much more? enough to fit "Hello, world!" PLUS one more for the null-terminator character `'\0'`, which determines the end of the string. so you'll need to declare an array of 14 characters.

For a bit more in-depth explanation on working with string and the null-character, i suggest [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/). Whilst it is a C++ page it covers stuff that is common for both C and C++ (as C++ is based on C)

Also, as Pearsonartphoto said, you can just declare your array as

```
char message[] = "Hello, World!";
```

However, if this is for school or a uni assignment, make sure you've been taught to do it this way, because sometimes you can be deducted marks for 'rushing ahead'. The idea of these sort of questions is to teach the funementals, and HOW and WHY certain things work, they may not be the easiest or most efficient way of doing things (the type of stack-smash you're getting is still causing problems in major systems today because programmers forget to check sizes etc).

Answer (score 2):

Your `message` array needs to be at least one character longer than the string you copy into it (remember you need to hold the implicit `'\0'` null terminator as well).

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, Hello World! is too long. Much easier would be to do the following

```
char message[]="Hello World!";
```

Which will be the right size automatically.

Comment: Oops... That's what I get for using too many programming languages at the same time...

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem when i defined a struct in this way:

```
struct data {
...variables...
char text[];
};
```

This won't give ANY WARNING but in my case caused a stack smashing error.
I solved substituting that with

```
char text[100];
```