# stack smashing detected while reading file

Tags: c++

I have made a method to read data from a `input.txt` file
here is the code

```
void readData()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("input.txt");
    char v[1], w[1];
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        string line;
        getline(myfile, line, ' ');
        strcpy(v, line.c_str());
        getline(myfile, line);
        strcpy(w, line.c_str());
        //graph->addEdge(v[0], w[0]);
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

I am trying to get two vertices from input file whose one line contains two character. and I have made a `addEdge` method in my `Graph` class which takes two char as input to add it into graph.

here is my input.txt file

```
A B
A C
F D
D C
U I
U D
B I
F B
```

but when I run the programme it is giving error

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I do not understand why this error is comming. I have read other questions on stackoverflow for this error. But none of them are getting error while reading a file.

one more thing I want to add, if I remove the line `strcpy(w, line.c_str());` then the code is working, maybe this line is causing the error. I am not sure about that.
please help me out in this error.
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Null termination.

Comment: What do you expect `strcpy(w, line.c_str());` to do? Do you have lines that are not empty? How shall these fit into `w`? And if you are in C++, why don't you use `std:.string` instead of C style strings?

Comment: Did you read this question [c stack smashing detected - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712413/c-stack-smashing-detected)? Although the language is different the cause is the same, you should be able to figure out the problem yourself.

Comment: The declaration `char v[1]` says that `v` is a string that can hold exactly ZERO characters - plus a terminating `nul` character.

Comment: An array of size 1 is pretty pointless. Think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate problem is that a single-character C-style string occupies **two** bytes: the character and the NUL terminator. So your arrays are too short and you're writing outside their bounds.

However, you don't need arrays at all. You can just store the appropriate character:

```
void readData()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("input.txt");
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        string line;
        getline(myfile, line, ' ');
        char v = line[0];
        getline(myfile, line);
        char w = line[0];
        graph->addEdge(v, w);
    }
}
```

Also note that there's no need to explicitly `close` the file. Its destructor will do it for you just fine.

---

Note that the code above does not do any error checking. In production code, you should always test the result of input operations (such as the `getline` call) for success. The simplest solution could look like this:

```
void readData()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("input.txt");
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        string line;
        if (!getline(myfile, line, ' ') || line.empty())
            break;
        char v = line[0];
        if (!getline(myfile, line) || line.empty())
            break;
        char w = line[0];
        graph->addEdge(v, w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth checking the string isn't empty before accessing its first character?

Comment: I have a question ```Also note that there's no need to explicitly close the file. Its destructor will do it for you just fine.``` which destructor you are talking about?? I am not that good at c++ .

Comment: @AbhishekPatil The destructor of `std::ifstream`.